# Supervised Learning Random Forest by Group

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have a training data set like this (but much larger):

```
       Group   PID  Var1  Var2  Best
    0    111     1     1     1     1
    1    111     2     2     1     2
    2    111     3     1     2     2
    3    112     1     1     2     2
    4    112     2     2     1     1
    5    113     1     1     2     2
    6    113     2     1     1     2
    7    113     3     2     1     1
    8    113     4     3     2     2
```

Where each group (rows that share a group number) contains a list of people (each unique PID within each group), and one person within the group with Best = 1, and the rest with Best = 2. My goal is to use this training data predict which person in each group is the best (Best = 1) based on Var1 and Var2.

I have played around with Scikit learn and have tried to use the random forest model to predict Best for the test data, but it does not account for the groups and can assign Best = 1 for more than one PID per group.

I was wondering how to train/run the model so that it learns to assign a single Best = 1 per group instead of assigning it across all rows and groups. Pointing me in the direction of helpful resources would be just as good as I'm not exactly sure where to go for help on this.

Comment: Since your features are `Var1` & `Var2`, it will try to predict `Best` from these two columns. It will predict each sample independently and thus can result in many ones in the same group.

Comment: Ok, I'll try adding Group and PID to the features and see if that produces the desired results. Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid it's not gonna be better. You should use `OneHotEncoder` to encode the feature `Group` otherwise it's gonna rank the groups between them and it does mean anything. Why should group `111` be less important than group `112` (just because `111 < 112`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? I'm not familiar with OneHotEncoder. What does it mean to "encode the feature Group"?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Answer (score 2):

When a feature is *not* a well-ordered metric -- such as a discrete classification -- we use one-hot encoding.  This means that for **N** classes (different values) of the original feature, we create a family of **N** features, exactly *one* of which will be "good" (usually **1**), while the others are "bad" (typically **0**).  You can read this as a set of Boolean functions: isGroup111(), isGroup112(), ...

```
   Group111 Group112 Group113   PID  Var1  Var2  Best
0     1        0        0        1     1     1     1
1     1        0        0        2     2     1     2
2     1        0        0        3     1     2     2
3     0        1        0        1     1     2     2
4     0        1        0        2     2     1     1
5     0        0        1        1     1     2     2
6     0        0        1        2     1     1     2
7     0        0        1        3     2     1     1
8     0        0        1        4     3     2     2
```

Comment: Discard `PID`. I don't think ID's will bring any significant info to the classifier ...

Comment: I left in in the table for completeness.  You're quite correct that it should not be a feature in the evaluation.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks! Are there memory concerns if there are a huge number of different groups?

Comment: It depends on your storage methods.  At worst, this replaces a short int with three short ints (three classes).  If your DB is responsive to data types, you can replace this with a 3-bit map: one Boolean for each group.  The direct answer is to try it and track your memory usage.

Comment: @Nizag : Yes if you have a lot of categories, using a `OneHotEncoder` will lead to memory issues if you don't have enough memory